# How to know firestore storage size?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble finding information that should normally be easy to find: the size of the Firestore database. I come across various charts for reads, writes, and deletions (lol), but I can't find the simple and obvious information of how much my database weighs. So, I'm a beginner and maybe I'm missing something, and perhaps the information is easy to find after all. I thank you in advance for your help and patience."

"Of course, I've searched the web and even watched videos, some of which were focused on the Google Cloud console. However, I haven't found any information that appears to be up-to-date for 2023, and I haven't found the simple information I'm looking for: the weight of the database."